# why HighChart is not visible in asp.net

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, highcharts

i am trying to implement High Chart in .aspx page so i tried below code

in .aspx page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="HighChartjs.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>


    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#container').highcharts({
                title: {
                    text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
                    x: -20 //center
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
                    x: -20
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                        'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Temperature (°C)'
                    },
                    plotLines: [{
                        value: 0,
                        width: 1,
                        color: '#808080'
                    }]
                },
                tooltip: {
                    valueSuffix: '°C'
                },
                legend: {
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    align: 'right',
                    verticalAlign: 'middle',
                    borderWidth: 0
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Tokyo',
                    data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
                }, {
                    name: 'New York',
                    data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
                }, {
                    name: 'Berlin',
                    data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
                }, {
                    name: 'London',
                    data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
                }]
            });
        });

       </script>
     </head>
    <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>


            <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

after running this code in browser chart is not loading ( is not visible in browser )  ...
where i made error

thanks......

Answer (score 0):

1st i need to call jQuery ....now its working fine ....

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```